# Can someone explain why my dash isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating a game for my school final project, and I'm trying to add a simple dash, but for some reason it refuses to work. I even put a debug to see if it's doing something but nothing happens.
I've been searching online to see but I can't figure why my dash doesn't work. I'm using a coroutine to make the dash and calling it in the update method, everything else works wonders.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Core : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float move;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float jump = 6f;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundCheckRadius;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    private bool isTouchingGround;
    public int MaxHealth = 100;
    public int CurrentHealth;
    bool isgrounded;
    private bool canDash;
    private bool isDashing;
    private float dashingPower = 24f;
    private float dashingTime = 0.2f;
    private float dashingCoolDown = 1f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        CurrentHealth = MaxHealth;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isDashing)
        {
            return;
        }

        isTouchingGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isTouchingGround)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump));
        }

        move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);
     
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)&& canDash)
        {
            Debug.Log("deste um Dash");
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
        }
    }

    void takeDamage(int amount)
    {
        CurrentHealth += amount;

        if (CurrentHealth <= 0)
        {
            //we are the OOF
            //poe uma animação de morte
            // mete o morreste ou game over sé sexy eu futuro(na boa eu passado)
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        canDash = false;
        isDashing = true;
        float originalGravity = rb.gravityScale;
        rb.gravityScale = 0f;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x * dashingPower, 0f);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
        rb.gravityScale = originalGravity;
        isDashing= false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCoolDown);
        canDash = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say "nothing happens" does it print your debug for q and candash? if you add debugs to your dash do you see them?

Comment: it doesn't print "deste um Dash" nothing appears in the consule

Comment: well then, either you aint pressing Q (or what would be Q on a US keyboard) or candash is not true....  and at no point do i see you set candash to true at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Before dashing you're checking for `Q` key and `canDash` true, so you need to set `canDash = true` in your `Start` method when game begins.